# It is possible to have multiple webservers running on same port inside one network?

Tags: router, ip, network

Lets say we have a network A with two webservers inside it, S1 and S2, both hosting a website on port 80. When a client from a different network is addressing A:80, which host inside network A, will receive the message?

Comment: The destination address is on the IP packet, and the host with that address will receive the packet.

Comment: But the destination address is A, it doesn't mention any host inside A like S1 or S2

Comment: The destination address is the IP address of the destination host, not a network address.

Comment: Exactly, but my question is how does the router know to which host it should forward the paket?

Comment: The router builds a frame for the destination host based on the destination IP address an sends it out the interface for that network. For some LAN protocols, e.g. rthernet, that involves ARP. The router simply looks at the destination address and its routing table to determine the next interface.

Comment: Okay maybe my question wasn't clear: We have a client with a private IP address of 192.168.2.107 inside the public network 10.10.10.20, the client sends a request to another network 14.14.14.55:80, inside this network are two hosts 192.168.2.103 (S1) and 192.168.2.105 (S2) running a webserver on port 80. Now how does the router with public IP 14.14.14.55 know to which host the request was meant for? S1 or S2?

Comment: You mean NAPT, and you can only forward port 80 to one of those hosts, which is a big problem for NAPT, which is why companies with multiple servers using the same port but public IPv4 addresses. NAPT really has nothing to do with routing, except that a router is often a convenient place to do it.

Comment: @tonik Please edit your question so it contains what you're actually asking. We're trying to create a Q&A database that people with similar problems can use. Hiding your question within a comment makes it useless.

Comment: "_When a client from a different network is addressing A:80_" Again, hosts do not set a network as a destination address. Hosts address packets with a host destination address.

Comment: @RonMaupin is it even possible to set a network as a destination address? What I meant with "addressing A:80" is addressing the destination address of the host.

Comment: With NAPT (public to private), the address is the NAPT device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading between the lines, you are asking about two servers on a private network using the same protocol port number and being contacted from the public network. That requires the NAPT (Network Address Port Translation) variant of NAT (Network Address Translation).

A limitation of NAPT is that you can only forward traffic for a particular protocol port to a single inside host, or use a round-robin method, but that will not let someone from the outside to choose the server.

Your example would require one of the inside servers to use a different protocol port. That is why businesses with multiple servers using the same protocol port get (buy) multiple public addresses.

Comment: Awesome this answers my question, thank you very much!

Comment: An alternative could be a reverse proxy that forwards requests based on the HTTP *host* header. Proxies and protocols above the transport layer are off-topic here, however.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, all you need is a Linux host running an open-source load-balancer running on it, eg. HAproxy/Ngnix, etc.

You can enable traffic to accept connections over port 80 on your Linux LB and share/load-balance traffic onto your internal server's ports can be 80 or any of your custom app ports.

Comment: Unfortunately, hosts/servers are off-topic here, as are protocols above OSI lare-4, e.g. HTTP. It is not possible to distinguish the servers using IP and TCP, so you can only havr one from the perspective of what is on-topic here when using NAPT.